# How can I wait for something to happen before going onto the next value in a table?

Tags: lua

I'm pretty new so please don't harm me,

How could I get a for loop to wait until a set event, before going onto the next item in a table?

```
for i,v in pairs( positions ) do
    if myPosition == v) then 
       -- *go to the next value*
    else
       -- *wait for myPosition == v to be true*
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an inner loop that does whatever it is that changes `myPosition`.

```
for i, v in pairs(positions) do
  -- *wait for myPosition == v to be true*
  while myPosition ~= v do
    doTheThingThatChangesMyPosition()
  end
  -- *go to the next value*
end
```